pass an object.property of string to a function as an string argument
I suffer  this failure:

[dcc64 Error] Unit_Copy.pas(543): E2197 Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter

Here comes an example code for this error:
Type
  MyClass = class
  private
    FLname  : String;
  public
    ...
    property Lname: string read GetLname write SetLname;
  end;
    
function Writeteststr(var newString) : Boolean;
begin
  // does some sting processing ....
end; 

The calling code is using this function:
Writeteststr(FMyClass.Lname)

Why can't I pass a class property of string type to my function with a string argument?

You're effectively doing Writeteststr( FMyClass.GetLname() ), passing a function's result (which is always read-only) as var (which needs write access). Just don't declare your function parameter as var (it's not even a String data type).

Your function takes a var reference as input, so it requires an actual variable to bind the var to.  But your property is using getter/setter methods instead, so there is no variable to bind to (it can't bind to the getter's return value).
Simply get rid of the var:
function Writeteststr(newString: string) : Boolean;

Or, change it to const if the function will not modify the string:
function Writeteststr(const newString: string) : Boolean;

